# Unable to use constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

So, I don't know why the program below does not print `1`.

```
class ck {
    static  int a,c;
    ck(int b, int d){
        a=b;
        c=d;
    }
    ck (){
        a=0;
        c=0;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ck nnn=new ck();
        ck nn=new ck(5,1);

        System.out.print(nnn.a+nn.c);
    }
}
```

Can you please explain?

Comment: It prints  `6`  if that helps. :)

Comment: that would be because a and c are static, thus they are class fields not instance variables. in other words, nnn and nn share the share a and c and by the time you compute the sum nnn.a=nn.a=ck.a=5

Comment: if you want to obtain 1, just take "static" out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this a puzzle?

The reasons is because you have declared variables `a` and `c` as `static`, meaning that they are not attached to the instance but have become "global" variables in the scope of the class `ck`

```
static  int a,c;
```

So by calling the second constructor, you are setting the global variables `a` to `5` and `c` to `1`, and when you then later print `a + c` (it doesn't matter what instance you prefix them with), the result is `5 + 1 == 6`.

Solution, if you want to print `1`, is to change the above line to:

```
int a,c;
```

Comment: haha not a puzzle, I just wanted to see how much I know.  So basically if i can get rid of that static keyword, i can get it to print 1?

Comment: Yes remove the `static` and you will get `1`

Answer (score 6):

You declared `a` and `c` static so the second time the constructor gets called (here `ck nn=new ck(5,1);`) it overrides the values for both objects `nnn` and `nn`. Therefore `nnn.a + nn.c` is `5 + 1 = 6`

Answer (score 0):

It is because in java, there is only a single copy maintained for static variables.
When the line- `ck nnn=new ck();` executes, the static variables are initialized as a=0 & c=0.

When again, ck nn=new ck(5,1); executes, it is the same a & b as above, to which the new values (5 & 1) are assigned.

Hence, it will print 6.